# Android app crashes when reopened from icon

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I created a game with Unity and built it for Android, the game was running fine until I integrated with Firebase.

The game has multiple 3rd party services integrated:

- Google game services.
- Facebook SDK.
- Photon.
- Firebase.

When I integrated Firebase I had multiple conflicts with Android manifest, so I created a new one.

Afterwards this started occurring: when I open the application and send it to the background then open it again from running apps the game resumes fine, but if I press the game icon again the game crashes.

Some mentioned it might be a problem with the Android manifest so I’ve uploaded, I don’t really know much about manifests so If any can help I’d really appreciate it.

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="${applicationId}" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService" android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
              android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                 android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.AppInviteDialogActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb1362238983845280" />
    <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1362238983845280" android:exported="true" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: post your log error.

Comment: I don't know how to !

Comment: Connect your phone to Android Studio and monitor Logcat. When the crash happens, you'll get a stack trace in Logcat. Post it here.

Comment: Yes as @AKarthik10 mentioned, we won't be able to help until we see the error.

Comment: goo.gl/c12keR
here is file of full logcat using adb command line, hope this is what you asked for

Comment: This part in the log might be relevant
https://pastebin.com/eKkpeEk9

Also it seems that Unity tried to print a stack trace but couldn't
https://pastebin.com/AbGH4cpS